# Is it possible to create a lookup column with a list of all lists on the site using a WSDL data source?

Tags: 2010, list, lookup-column, collection, wsdl

I have a list in which I want the user to be able to select the name of 1 or more lists/libraries that exist on the account. I know I can use `_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetListCollection` to get a list of lists and I figure I could create a WSDL data source  with it. But I can't figure out how to use that WSDL data source as the source for a lookup column.

And/or if there is any other way to do what I need?

Comment: You may need to do this in an application page. You could populate a drop down list with WSDL being the data source.

Comment: A little more information please? What is an application page? My company doesn't let do any advanced development. I only have access to SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Okay. I didn't realize you weren't a developer. Application pages are deployed via VS. We'll need to see if SPD can do this another way.

Comment: You'll want to create a custom form using InfoPath. Take a look at this video on making data connections via InfoPath. I'll look for more references. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85b7ftTJYo8

Comment: Here are steps for making a connection to a web service in InfoPath. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2012/08/17/want-to-call-sharepoint-2010-web-services-within-browser-based-infopath-2010-forms.aspx

Comment: @jpollar I hadn't thought of Infopath. I am wondering if my company allows it. I will try this tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Yep...let me know if you need help.